# How to save img uploaded into localStorage?

Tags: jquery, file-upload, file-io, local-storage

I'm working harder on my extension and I've troubles to save img in localStorage and delete it from button.

here is part on my **HTML**:

```
<a href="#" id="die">DELETE IMG</a>
<input type='file' id="imgInp" />
<div id="canvas">
    <img id="uploaded" src="#" alt="your image" />
</div>
```

and **script** that I tried to edit:

```
function readURL() {

     $('#uploaded').attr('src', '').hide();
        if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        $(reader).load(function(e) {
            $('#uploaded').attr('src', e.target.result) 
            localStorage.setItem('img', e.target.result);
        });
        reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
    }
}

$('#uploaded').load(function(e) {       
    $(this).show();
}).hide();

$("#imgInp").change(readURL);

$('#die').click(function() {
    localStorage.clear();
    window.location.reload();
});
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/remibenault/Bbmbe/19/) with the code

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

LocalStorage only supports strings, so what you need to do  is turn the image into a Data URL. You can do it by loading it into canvas element and then saving in local storage .
Have a read on these :-

[How to save an image to localStorage and display it on the next page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183180/how-to-upload-an-image-save-it-to-localstorage-and-then-display-it-on-the-next)

https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/02/saving-images-and-files-in-localstorage/