# Is it possible to set background-image to an image from the user's pc with javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'am working on a site, and I'd like to give users the option to choose their own background.
So is it possible to browse the client's computer for an image, and without uploading it to the server, setting it as background?

Comment: if u don't upload it wil disappear ever time u refresh the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `localStorage` is your friend. It will ensure that whenever your site is accessed from this person's computer on that particular browser, the image will show up. See this answer: [How to save an image to localStorage and display it on the next page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183180/how-to-save-an-image-to-localstorage-and-display-it-on-the-next-page)