# Store bulk images in $localStorage - Angular JS

Tags: php, angularjs, canvas, html5-canvas, angular-local-storage

I'm using `$localStorage` service to store data in browser's cache. Actually I'm building a web application ( in `angularjs` and `PHP` ) on which user can upload multiple images on **`canvas`**, manipulate with them. What I was doing, when user uploads **image/s**, I was uploading this image to server and when user removes, I am unlinking it from the server but this approach only increases my server space with `MBs/GBs` of garbage data.

I'm looking to change my approach. **Can I upload bulk of images on `localStorage` and when user submits his/her campaign, only then all of the images will send to the server ?** Is there any **approach** can I go with ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it, and you can read about the sole technicalities of how to achieve that in the answer to this question: [How to save an image to localStorage and display it on the next page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183180/how-to-save-an-image-to-localstorage-and-display-it-on-the-next-page) (basically it boils down to saving a Base64-encoded image as a string)

Mind that most browsers can only **store up to several MB of data** (depending on each browser, e.g. 5 for Chrome) in localStorage, so you will be limited by that.

Comment: Sounds like fun. Let me make a try first.