# Checked the checkbox if localStorage returns value true

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, local-storage

I am trying to save multiple select values in local storage and the data is setting and getting successfully in and from local storage but the box is not checked by the jquery.

Here is the [`fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/VPC86/237/) of my code and below is the jquery code I am using :

```
$('.cmn').on('click', function() {
            var fav, favs = [];
            $('.cmn').each(function() { // run through each of the checkboxes
            fav = {class: $(this).attr('class'), value: $(this).prop('checked')};
                //console.debug(fav);
                favs.push(fav);
            });
            localStorage.setItem("payment", JSON.stringify(favs));
        });

        $(document).ready(function() {
            var payment = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('payment'));

            if (!payment.length) {return};
            //console.debug(payment);

            for (var i=0; i<payment.length; i++) {
                console.debug(payment[i]);
                //alert("."+payment[i].class);
                $("."+payment[i].class).prop('checked', payment[i].value);
            }
        });
```

Comment: "but it is not working fine". What does that mean? Please explain the problem.

Comment: yes the result is fine as you can see in the console but it is not checking the box

Comment: BTW, most people won't click links in questions. It's up to you as the question asker to clearly say what your issue is. And have you tried debugging this?

Comment: Please post the "*[mcve]*" code in your question, not in an external resource.

Comment: Actually i have no idea how to tell that thing all i want is to check the box which have true values after getting local data but it is not working fine

Comment: Looks like   payment[i].class is always cmn, yo do dot differentiate the input textboxes by an id for example, they all have same class.

Comment: can i do this with class or not?

Comment: what `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('payment'));` is return

Comment: You can do it with class but you must declare cmn_1, cmn_2 etc different classes for each input.

Comment: `[Object { class="cmn",  value=false}, Object { class="cmn",  value=true}, Object { class="cmn",  value=true}, Object { class="cmn",  value=true}, Object { class="cmn",  value=false}, Object { class="cmn",  value=false}, Object { class="cmn",  value=false}, Object { class="cmn",  value=false}, Object { class="cmn",  value=false}, Object { class="cmn",  value=false}, Object { class="cmn",  value=false}, Object { class="cmn",  value=false}]` this is what it returns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VPC86/238/)**.

You should add the index `i` in `:eq()` to specify the index of the element since all the elements have the same class `cmn` :

```
$("."+payment[i].class+':eq('+i+')').prop('checked', payment[i].value);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I never heard about `:eq` so i didn't use it

Comment: Yes really. Also want to know one thing can i store image and div value too in localStorage or not?

Comment: Check this fiddle store the image then get it using the `outerHTML` attribute : http://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/VPC86/241/

Answer (score 1):

add counter variable in order to track which checkbox you are targeting

```
$('.cmn').on('click', function() {
            var fav, favs = [], i=0;
            $('.cmn').each(function() { // run through each of the checkboxes
            fav = {class: $(this).attr('class'), value: $(this).prop('checked'), index: (i++)};
                //console.debug(fav);
                favs.push(fav);
            });
            localStorage.setItem("payment", JSON.stringify(favs));
        });

        $(document).ready(function() {
            var payment = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('payment'));

            if (!payment.length) {return};
            //console.debug(payment);

            for (var i=0; i<payment.length; i++) {
                //console.debug(payment[i]);
                //alert("."+payment[i].class);
                $(".cmn:eq("+payment[i].index+")").prop('checked', payment[i].value);
            }
        });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VPC86/239/

Comment: Thanks for your answer it is also working fine but you are little bit late to answer but thanks for your answer i will remember this too. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Also want to know one thing can i store image and div value too in localStorage or not?

Comment: can you please tell me how can i remove all data of checkbox in localstorage

Comment: `window.localStorage.clear();` this is clear all information or by using this `window.localStorage.remove('payment');`

Comment: this link helps you to store image in localStorage http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183180/how-to-save-an-image-to-localstorage-and-display-it-on-the-next-page