# JSON.parse() returns an empty object

Tags: javascript, json, local-storage

I wan to store the event object of the input type file in local Storage but when i convert the object into JSON String it returns an empty object.

```
var image = document.getElementById('image');
    image.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
        var img = e.target.files[0];
        localStorage.setItem('img', JSON.stringify(img))
        var getImg = localStorage.getItem('img');
        console.log(JSON.parse(getImg));

    });
```

Comment: Log `img`. What's the output?

Comment: See [How to save an image to localStorage...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183180/how-to-save-an-image-to-localstorage-and-display-it-on-the-next-page)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to save an image to localStorage and display it on the next page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183180/how-to-save-an-image-to-localstorage-and-display-it-on-the-next-page)

Answer (score -1):

If the image object is the binary contents of an image file then it cannot be stringified to a valid JSON.