# store webview data into an app inside cache folder

Tags: android, caching, webview

/*[cache in webview]
[1]http://tutorials.jenkov.com/android/android-web-apps-using-android-webview.html#caching-web-resources-in-html5-local-storage

I have used this link for my app. i am using webview in an app and i want to store the html , images,css into an app in cache folder.
store webview data into aan app inside cache folder.
please guide me on this.    */

Comment: StackOverflow is not for "guiding" ... you are welcome to ask a real question(of course if it wasn't asked already)

Comment: i am actually developing an app. and i am stuck at storing data into an app, i have used this code but didint work correctly. as i am fresher thats why said guide me

Comment: StackOverflow is [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) site ... it is not make/fix (not)my code to work as I want for free service ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the link, you can use local storage, that can be done by using javascript.

From my knowledge, you can save and retrieve values using javascript.

```
// setting
localStorage.setItem("firstname", "First Name");

// Retrieve
document.getElementById("givenId").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("firstname");
```

And you can check whether your app-web browser supports localstorage by using below code.

```
// Check iuf your browser supports local storage
if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
// supports
}
```

The code for setting from android webview is for enabling the web browser

```
webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

Comment: my website contains images also. in .jpg. should i have to store it in folder already or download when app opens for the first time.?

Comment: either save image url, or do something like this link.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183180/how-to-save-an-image-to-localstorage-and-display-it-on-the-next-page