# JavaScript/HTML load image via file input with localStorage

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I am trying to allow a user to upload their own file, and without a database load the same file when they go back onto the page. So I figured localStorage would be the way to go. However, I don't know how I can allow localStorage to load the uploaded image (preferably with `<input type="file">`). Thanks.

Comment: Please checkout this question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183180/how-to-save-an-image-to-localstorage-and-display-it-on-the-next-page)

Comment: Oh... I didn't see that question. But thanks for the help.