# image saved on local storage pass to input file

Tags: javascript

I have successfully stored a base64 image to the local storage.

I have tried and failed in adding the stored value to an input file field.

```
document.getElementsByName("inputfieldname")[0].setAttribute("value", getSavedValue("thesavedkey"));

<input type="file" name="inputfieldname">
```

Answer (score 2):

you can't set a value in this way to a `file` type input due to legacy security vulnerabilities.

Comment: There seems to be a solution here. Just can't seem to get my head over it.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183180/how-to-save-an-image-to-localstorage-and-display-it-on-the-next-page

Comment: @badboy this is just parsing the image into base64 format and then saving to localStorage, and then showing it somewhere, like input field (type=text). however, what you wanted is to set the value of a `type=file` input, which is impossible. but if you want to send the base64 data to your server and then create image from it on your server, it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById('mytext').value =  = window.sessionStorage.getItem('user')
```

try above one.