# how do I display the image that was saved to local storage?

Tags: javascript, image, vue.js, vuex

My problem is I saved an image to the local storage but when I retrieve it from vuex and paste it into the code the image does not appear.

The object I get from vuex:

```
place: {
    ....
    imgPath: C:\Users\...\Pictures\abc\b\first.jpg
    ....
}
```

and vuetify code:

```
<v-img v-bind:src="place.imgPath"></v-img>
```

Comment: `imgPath: C:\Users\...\Pictures\abc\b\first.jpg` - well, that doesn't look right

Comment: put the image in server directory and load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vue is intended to be run on a webserver. Including files directly from your local hard drive is a security problem and thus not allowed. Either include the image in your assets so Vue can include it that way, or host the image on a domain somewhere, so you can hot link it from there. Again, paths starting with a drive letter will **not** (and should not) work.

Answer (score 0):

here you have a stack question on image in localstorage and accessing it:
[How to save an image to localStorage and display it on the next page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183180/how-to-save-an-image-to-localstorage-and-display-it-on-the-next-page)

and here the vue official doc for client side storage:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/client-side-storage.html

should be enough to answer your issue :)

Comment: Localstorage is my local repository on my computer