# How come my blob value changes after I refresh the web page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to load an image from cache. It works whenever i switch between different tabs of the website, but when I reload the page, I get the default img icon instead of the actual image. Below is how I'm currently doing it. This is in reactJS

```
localStorage.setItem('image', URL.createObjectURL(imageFile));

setProfilePic(localStorage.getItem('image'))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL - *The URL lifetime is tied to the document in the window on which it was created*. Also, this way it's an URL, not a blob.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to save an image to localStorage and display it on the next page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183180/how-to-save-an-image-to-localstorage-and-display-it-on-the-next-page)