# Failed to upload image, React js

Tags: reactjs, mern

I am new to MERN stack. I am try to create a movie app these days by watching tutorials. In project, Admin can create movies. when he create a movie he should upload a image as well. But when i choose a image file from local storage and click submit button, it always says "Failed to upload the image".

My CreateMovie.jsx file is below

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

import {
  useCreateMovieMutation,
  useUploadImageMutation,
} from "../../redux/api/movies.js";
import { useFetchGenresQuery } from "../../redux/api/genre.js";

import { toast } from "react-toastify";

const CreateMovie = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const [movieData, setMovieData] = useState({
    name: "",
    year: 0,
    detail: "",
    cast: [],
    rating: 0,
    image: null,
    genre: "",
  });

  const [selectedImage, setSelectedImage] = useState(null);

  const [
    createMovie,
    { isLoading: isCreatingMovie, error: createMovieErrorDetail },
  ] = useCreateMovieMutation();

  const [
    uploadImage,
    { isLoading: isUploadingImage, error: uploadImageErrorDetails },
  ] = useUploadImageMutation();

  const { data: genres, isLoading: isLoadingGenres } = useFetchGenresQuery();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (genres) {
      setMovieData((prevData) => ({
        ...prevData,
        genre: genres[0]?.id || "",
      }));
    }
  }, [genres]);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;

    if (name === "genre") {
      const selectedGenre = genres.find((genre) => genre.name === value);

      setMovieData((prevData) => ({
        ...prevData,
        genre: selectedGenre ? selectedGenre._id : "",
      }));
    } else {
      setMovieData((prevData) => ({
        ...prevData,
        [name]: value,
      }));
    }
  };

  const handleImageChange = (e) => {
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    setSelectedImage(file);
  };

  const handleCreateMovie = async () => {
    try {
      if (
        !movieData.name ||
        !movieData.year ||
        !movieData.detail ||
        !movieData.cast ||
        !selectedImage
      ) {
        toast.error("Please fillllll fill all required fields");
        return;
      }

      let uploadedImagePath = null;

      if (selectedImage) {
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("image", selectedImage);

        const uploadImageResponse = await uploadImage(formData);

        if (uploadImageResponse.data) {
          uploadedImagePath = uploadImageResponse.data.image;
        } else {
          console.error("Failed to upload image: ", uploadImageErrorDetails);
          toast.error("Failed to upload image");
          return;
        }

        await createMovie({
          ...movieData,
          image: uploadedImagePath,
        });

        navigate("/admin/movies-list");

        setMovieData({
          name: "",
          year: 0,
          detail: "",
          cast: [],
          ratings: 0,
          image: null,
          genre: "",
        });

        toast.success("Movie Added to Database Successfully.");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Failed to create movie: ", createMovieErrorDetail);
      toast.error(
        `Failed to create movie: ${createMovieErrorDetail?.message} `
      );
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="container flex justify-center items-center mt-4">
      <form>
        <p className="text-green-200 w-[50rem] text-2xl mb-4">Create Movie</p>

        <div className="mb-4">
          <label className="block">
            Name:
            <input
              type="text"
              name="name"
              value={movieData.name}
              onChange={handleChange}
              className="border px-2 py-1 w-full"
            />
          </label>
        </div>

        <div className="mb-4">
          <label className="block">
            Year:
            <input
              type="number"
              name="year"
              value={movieData.year}
              onChange={handleChange}
              className="border px-2 py-1 w-full"
            />
          </label>
        </div>

        <div className="mb-4">
          <label className="block">
            Detail:
            <textarea
              name="detail"
              value={movieData.detail}
              onChange={handleChange}
              className="border px-2 py-1 w-full"
            ></textarea>
          </label>
        </div>

        <div className="mb-4">
          <label className="block">
            Cast (comma-separated):
            <input
              type="text"
              name="cast"
              value={movieData.cast.join(", ")}
              onChange={(e) =>
                setMovieData({ ...movieData, cast: e.target.value.split(", ") })
              }
              className="border px-2 py-1 w-full"
            />
          </label>
        </div>

        <div className="mb-4">
          <label className="block">
            Genre:
            <select
              name="genre"
              value={movieData.genre}
              onChange={handleChange}
              className="border px-2 py-1 w-full"
            >
              {isLoadingGenres ? (
                <option>Loading genres...</option>
              ) : (
                genres.map((genre) => (
                  <option key={genre.id} value={genre.id}>
                    {genre.name}
                  </option>
                ))
              )}
            </select>
          </label>
        </div>

        <div className="mb-4">
          <label
            style={
              !selectedImage
                ? {
                    border: "1px solid #888",
                    borderRadius: "5px",
                    padding: "8px",
                  }
                : {
                    border: "0",
                    borderRadius: "0",
                    padding: "0",
                  }
            }
          >
            {!selectedImage && "Upload Image"}

            <input
              type="file"
              accept="image/*"
              onChange={handleImageChange}
              style={{ display: !selectedImage ? "none" : "block" }}
            />
          </label>
        </div>

        <button
          type="button"
          onClick={handleCreateMovie}
          className="bg-teal-500 text-white px-4 py-2 rounded"
          // disabled={isCreatingMovie || isUploadingImage}
        >
          {isCreatingMovie || isUploadingImage
            ? "Creating ..."
            : "Create Movie"}
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CreateMovie;
```

My movies.js file as below.

```
import { apiSlice } from "./apiSlice.js";

import { MOVIE_URL, UPLOAD_URL } from "../constants.js";

export const moviesApiSlice = apiSlice.injectEndpoints({
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getAllMovies: builder.query({
      query: () => `${MOVIE_URL}/all-movies`,
    }),

    createMovie: builder.mutation({
      query: (newMovie) => ({
        url: `${MOVIE_URL}/create-movie`,
        method: "POST",
        body: newMovie,
      }),
    }),

    updateMovie: builder.mutation({
      query: ({ id, updatedMovie }) => ({
        url: `${MOVIE_URL}/update-movie/${id}`,
        method: "PUT",
        body: updatedMovie,
      }),
    }),

    addMovieReview: builder.mutation({
      query: ({ id, rating, comment }) => ({
        url: `${MOVIE_URL}/${id}/reviews`,
        method: "POST",
        body: { rating, id, comment },
      }),
    }),

    deleteComment: builder.mutation({
      query: ({ movieId, reviewId }) => ({
        url: `${MOVIE_URL}/delete-comment`,
        method: "DELETE",
        body: { movieId, reviewId },
      }),
    }),

    deleteMovie: builder.mutation({
      query: (id) => ({
        url: `${MOVIE_URL}/delete-movie/${id}`,
        method: "DELETE",
      }),
    }),

    getSpecificMovie: builder.query({
      query: (id) => `${MOVIE_URL}/specific-movie/${id}`,
    }),

    uploadImage: builder.mutation({
      query: (formData) => ({
        url: `${UPLOAD_URL}`,
        method: "POST",
        body: formData,
      }),
    }),

    getNewMovies: builder.query({
      query: () => `${MOVIE_URL}/new-movies`,
    }),

    getTopMovies: builder.query({
      query: () => `${MOVIE_URL}/top-movies`,
    }),

    getRandomMovies: builder.query({
      query: () => `${MOVIE_URL}/random-movies`,
    }),
  }),
});

export const {
  useGetAllMoviesQuery,
  useCreateMovieMutation,
  useUpdateMovieMutation,
  useAddMovieReviewMutation,
  useDeleteCommentMutation,
  useGetSpecificMovieQuery,
  useUploadImageMutation,
  useDeleteMovieMutation,
  //
  useGetNewMoviesQuery,
  useGetTopMoviesQuery,
  useGetRandomMoviesQuery,
} = moviesApiSlice;
```

My constants.js as below

```
export const BASE_URL = "";
export const USERS_URL = "/api/v1/users";
export const GENRE_URL = "/api/v1/genre";
export const MOVIE_URL = "api/v1/movies";
export const UPLOAD_URL = "api/v1/upload";
```

In console , it provides as "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"and "Failed to upload image:  undefined, CreateMovie.jsx:95 "
Did I do somthing wrong Could you please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this thread, you could make a function that adds it to local storage and then you can use the data stored there as the src="" to the image., and then storing the value into local storage.

[How to save an image to localStorage and display it on the next page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183180/how-to-save-an-image-to-localstorage-and-display-it-on-the-next-page)

OR

If a video works better:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XZ8CjU9eaVA&t=423s

---