How to save an image to localStorage with onclick event? (javascript)
Without using back-end, I am trying to do a shopping cart feature so when I click an image on one page it saves the image to localStorage so it can be displayed on another page (a checkout page).
I was able to find working code that uploads an image, saves it to localStorage, and then displays on another page (reference: https://rb.gy/twpnak). However, I'm having trouble figuring out how to use an onclick event instead of uploading the picture from a library.
Here is that referenced code (use your own code editor to display as stack overflow will not display image):


  (function () {
    /** @type {Node} */
    var imgInput = document.getElementById("image-input"),
      /** @type {Node} */
      imgContainer = document.getElementById("image-container"),
      /** Restore image src from local storage */
      updateUi = function () {
        imgContainer.src = window.localStorage.getItem("image-base64");
      },
      /** Register event listeners */
      bindUi = function () {
        imgInput.addEventListener("change", function () {
          if (this.files.length) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
              window.localStorage.setItem("image-base64", e.target.result);
              updateUi();
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
          }
        }, false);
      };

    updateUi();
    bindUi();
  }());
<input type="file" id="image-input" />
  <img id="image-container" />



Once again, I'm just trying to click an image on one page, save it to localStorage, then have that image display on another page. I've tried using an onclick event on an image but am having trouble. Can someone help me with this please? Thank you
EDIT (SOLUTION):
I combined the code from How to save an image to localStorage and display it on the next page?, as well as used Amazon Q AI to get the answer I was looking for.
For my specific use case, I wanted to create an onclick event for an image on one page then have the image appear on another.
Here is a step-by-step explanation from Amazon Q:
"The provided code consists of two functions:
openImageInNewPage()
:
This function is responsible for opening an image in a new page.
It first calls the
getBase64Image()
function, passing the HTML element with the ID "bannerImg" as an argument.
The
getBase64Image()
function converts the image to a base64-encoded string and returns it.
The base64-encoded image data is then stored in the browser's localStorage using the key "imgData".
Finally, the function opens a new page with the URL "TESTING4.html".
getBase64Image(img)
:
This function takes an HTML image element as an argument and converts it to a base64-encoded string.
It creates a new

element and sets its width and height to match the dimensions of the input image.
It then uses the canvas's 2D rendering context to draw the image onto the canvas.
The function then calls the
canvas.toDataURL()
method to convert the canvas content to a base64-encoded data URL.
The function removes the "data:image/(png|jpg);base64," prefix from the data URL and returns the base64-encoded image data.
In summary, the code is designed to capture the contents of an HTML image element, convert it to a base64-encoded string, and store it in the browser's localStorage. This data can then be used to open the image in a new page."


        function openImageInNewPage() {
            var imgData = getBase64Image(document.getElementById('bannerImg'));
            localStorage.setItem("imgData", imgData);
            window.open("TESTING4.html");
        }

        function getBase64Image(img) {
            var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            canvas.width = img.width;
            canvas.height = img.height;

            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

            var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
            return dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
        }
    <img id="bannerImg" src="/resources/images/beatsbydre.jpg" onclick="openImageInNewPage()" />



"The purpose of this code is to display the image that was previously stored in the browser's localStorage. When the
openImageInNewPage()
function is called, it stores the base64-encoded image data in localStorage, and this HTML file is then opened to display that image."


 var imgData = localStorage.getItem("imgData");
 var img = document.getElementById("displayedImage");
 img.src = "data:image/png;base64," + imgData;
<img id="displayedImage" src="" />




Check this answer i'm sure it will help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183180/how-to-save-an-image-to-localstorage-and-display-it-on-the-next-page

I have looked over the answer you provided in the link multiple times. I'm still having trouble. I will continue to look over it

i was unaware of base64 code. It appears this was the problem. I need to convert my images to base64 code, which i used a converter online for (https://www.base64-image.de/). this seems to fix the problem i was having with broken images on second page

On image click, get the img element and check the src attribute, then save it in localstorage. add this event in your bindUi function
imgContainer.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    if (e?.target?.src) window.localStorage.setItem("image-base64", e.target.src);
})

